# How to use local files to a docker container

Tags: docker, graphql

My team wants to try this tool https://docs.basebox.io/getting-started/
it generates a secure backend with a postgres as the db via a graphql file which you compile with the bbc(basebox-compiler).
I found the docker images but cant figure out how to run them

```
docker pull gitea.basebox.health/basebox-distribution/dbproxy  
docker pull gitea.basebox.health/basebox-distribution/bbc  
docker pull gitea.basebox.health/basebox-distribution/broker
```

Here is how you use it apparently bbc, the basebox compiler

Usage: bbc [OPTIONS] <FILENAME>

Arguments:
<FILENAME>  Path and filename of GraphQL schema to compile

Options:
-q, --quiet
quiet operation
-o, --output-directory <OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>
Output directory for generated files; default is current
-p, --prefix <PREFIX>
Prefix for file name generation; defaults to the base name of the input file
-f, --force-overwrite
Overwrite existing output files?
-h, --help
Print help (see more with '--help')
-V, --version
Print version

I tried this using the docker image but it does not recognize the directory

`docker run gitea.basebox.health/basebox-distribution/bbc --prefix=testproject -o bbconf schema.graphql`

Error Message: Failed to read GraphQL schema file 'schema.graphql': No such file or directory (os error 2)

Any helpful advice would be much appreciated

I can not stop error messages from appearing on my screen please help.

Comment: `-v  <host path>:<path in container>` to mount a local directory into the container in the `docker run command`

Answer (score 0):

This can be frustrating the first couple of go-arounds with Docker if you're new to it.

Try updating your command to this (assuming either *nix or Mac ... powershell /windows you may have to adapt)

```bash
docker run --rm \
           -it \
           -v "$(pwd)/schema.graphql:/source/schema.graphql" \
           -v "$(pwd):/bbconf" \
           gitea.basebox.health/basebox-distribution/bbc \
           --prefix=testproject -o /bbconf /source/schema.graphql
```

Breakdown of the above:

1. `--rm` will remove the container after execution
2. `-it` will make the console of your container interactive
3. `-v "$(pwd)/schema.graphql:/source/schema.graphql"` will mount a volume with the file in question
4. `-v "$(pwd):/bbconf"` will mount the current directory under `/bbconf` in the container (running instance of the image)

Everything else more or less remains the same

The `--rm` is important otherwise you'll load up on *piles* of exited containers and if not careful will fill up your disk. You can *prune* exited containers with `docker container prune`.

The `-it` attaches a terminal so your foreground running container can be interacted with.